# QueryDsl distinct query too slow

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa, querydsl

I am using QueryDsl in Java with an Oracle Database.

My query looks like this (Real names changed to dummy names, but the query is exactly the same):

```java
QTableA qTabA = QTableA.tableA;
QTableB qTabB = QTableA.tableB;
QTableC qTabC = QTableA.tableC;


List<ResultClass> result = queryFactory
        .select(Projections.constructor(ResultClass.class, qTabA.col1, qTabB.col1, qTabC.col1, qTabC.col2))
        .from(qTabA, qTabB, qTabC)
        .where(qTabA.col2.eq(123))
        .where(qTabA.col3.eq("test"))
        .where(qTabA.col4.eq(qTabB.col2))
        .where(qTabA.col4.eq(qTabC.col2))
        .distinct()
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .fetch();
```

The query would fetch around 1.5M rows, that's why I work with `offset()` and `limit()`.

I can't use `.iterator()` either because that fails when you want to commit your transaction while the iterator isn't closed yet.

Since I added the distinct, my query went really slow → unusable slow.

I can't do  the distinct check in the Java code though, because I can't load all the data in the memory at once (that's why I use offset and limit).

Does someone have a clue what I am doing wrong, or how I could do it better?

Comment: I see nothing strange in a query with `distinct` being slower than the corresponding query without `distinct`... what precisely doesn't seem to add up for you?

Comment: That its like 20x slower or something. Like unusable slow and a lot slower than the native Oracle SQL query @giorgiga

Comment: Maybe explicitly using [joins](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/reference/html_single/#d0e317) makes a difference, especially if a leftJoin or such might make DISTINCT superfluous, as DISTINCT is heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Any optimization that could have been done by limit and offset (i.e. stopping execution early) is basically eliminated by the distinct clause. This is just how distinct works out in your SQL query execution plan and is unrelated to QueryDSL.

You could consider creating a materialized view in your database that indexes the distinct values for this projection, and then query that in QueryDSL instead. The materialized view keeps track of the distinct names so that this intensive computation doesn't have to be done at query time. For this approach you will have to create an entity that maps to the materialized view, but that is perfectly well possible.

You can create a materialized view for Oracle using:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_names
REFRESH WITH ROWID 
AS SELECT  qTabA.col1, qTabB.col1, qTabC.col1, qTabC.col2 FROM tableA, tableB, tableC WHERE ...;
```

Then query in Querydsl:

```
queryFactory.select(QNameView.nameView).from(QNameView.nameView)
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(limit)
    .fetch();
```

You could also consider keyset pagination for very large pagination results. Because very large offsets will also affect your query performance (anything before the offset still has to be visited to be skipped...)

In order to do so, sort the result, and keep track of which name was the last one in your previous call. Then just add a where clause that eliminates any entries lower than that value, so you can omit the offset clause. Make sure to index this column on the materialized view for optimal performance.

Comment: limit and offset aren't there for query optimization purposes, but for java heap space purposes. If I could omit them I would, but I don't know any way without causing an OutOfMemoryError. Your solution seems good, thanks, but unfortunately not fitting for my purpose though.

Comment: The side effect of the offset and limit clause is a performance gain lost by the distinct clause. Your query doesn't execute - period. Its unrelated to Hibernate or QueryDSL. See for yourself using a JDBC query or a database shell.

Comment: No I meant that's how I use them. I have to use them because if I don't, I will run into memory issues. And yeah I have a workaround, but its hideous and I asked to question to maybe find something that works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try using `iterate()` instead of `fetch()`. Using `iterate()` you only have the current "window" in memory, so you can eliminate the `offset` and `limit` for memory issues. Make sure that you use the appropriate query handler (i.e. `HibernateHandler` for `HibernateQuery`)